# After initialize an array it shows me that he is undefined inside "then" of a promise function

Tags: angular, typescript, angular6

My code:

Typescript:

```
console.log(this.arr);
myService.getData(). then(data =>{
      console.log(this.arr);
      this.arr[0].myData = data;
 });
```

the logs in chrome
1. arr.length=1 - the array is Initialized
2. undefined

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That is because 'this' is different in both the scopes.

```
console.log(this.arr);
myService.getData(). then(data =>{
      console.log(this.arr);
      this.arr[0].myData = data;
 }.bind(this));
```

OR, even better:

```
var self = this;
console.log(self.arr);
myService.getData(). then(data =>{
      console.log(self.arr);
      self.arr[0].myData = data;
 });
```